# $\mathscr{O}(G/H, G/K) \cong (G/K)^H?$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

What I am about to ask is related to the question presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409911/is-the-space-of-g-maps-g-h-to-x-naturally-homeomorphic-to-xh/1415648).

> Let $X$ be a $G$-space, where $G$ is a (discrete) group. For a subgroup $H$ of $G$, define$$X^H = \{x : hx = x \text{ for all }h \in H\} \subset X;$$$X^H$ is the $H$-fixed point subspace of $X$. Topologize the set of functions $G/H \to X$ as the product of copies of $X$ indexed on the elements of $G/H$, and give the set of $G$-maps $G/H \to X$ the subspace topology. Is the space of $G$-maps $G/H \to X$ naturally homeomorphic to $X^H$?

There is an answer to the question above provided by Andrey Ryabichev as follows.

> The answer is Yes.
>
> By definition, $Maps(G/H,X)=\prod_{gH\in G/H}X_{gH}$. For define map $\phi:X^H\to Maps(G/H,X)$, let $gH$-th coordinate of $\phi(x)$ be $gx$. We see that $\phi$ is continuous inclusion (because fo all the compositions $X^H\to Maps(G/H,X)\to X_{gH}$ are continuous). If we take arbitrary $G$-map $f\in Maps(G/H,X)$ and $f(eH)=y$, it is easy to see that $y\in X^H$ and $f=\phi(y)$.
>
> Consider the projection $p_e$ of $\prod_{gH\in G/H}X_{gH}$ to the $X_{eH}$. By definition of topology of a product, $p_e$ will be continuous, and $p_e\circ\phi=Id_{X^H}$, so $X^H$ and space of $G$-maps have the same topology.

My question is, though, does it follow from Andrey Ryabichev's answer that$$\mathscr{O}(G/H, G/K) \cong (G/K)^H?$$Apologies if this question is kind of stupid...

Comment: Plug in $X=G/K$ no?

Comment: what is $\mathscr{O}(G/H, G/K)$?

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev The set of $G$-equivariant maps $G/H\to G/K$.

Comment: @whacka, and the notation $\mathscr{O}(G)$ from [the similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416342/passage-to-fixed-point-spaces-is-object-function-of-a-contravariant-functor)?

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev My best guess is Jeremy's comment. Peidao should show up and elaborate though.