# Passage to fixed point spaces is object function of a contravariant functor?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a $G$-space, where $G$ is a (discrete) group. For a subgroup $H$ of $G$, define$$X^H = \{x: hx = x \text{ for all }h \in H\} \subset X;$$$X^H$ is the $H$-fixed point subspace of $X$. Topologize the set of functions $G/H \to X$ as the product of copies of $X$ indexed on the elements $G/H$, and give the set of $G$-maps $G/H \to X$ the subspace topology.

What is the easiest way to see that that passage to fixed point spaces, $G/H \mapsto X^H$, is the object function of a contravariant functor $X^{(-)}: \mathscr{O}(G) \to \mathscr{U}$?

Comment: Is $G$ a discrete group? I presume $\mathscr{O}(G)$ means the orbit category? What is $\mathscr{U}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the category of $G$-sets, the morphisms $f:G/H\to X$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $X^H$; the correspondence sends $f$ to $f(H)$ (where the subgroup $H$, being a coset of itself, is an element of $G/H$). After checking that this correspondence is natural, you have that your alleged functor, $G/H\to X^H$, is, up to natural isomorphism, just the restriction of the representable functor Hom${}_{G-sets}(-,X)$.

Comment: I put a bounty on the question so there could be a comprehensive answer. Could you add a bit more detail?